# RAILS link_to external site, url is attribute of user table, like: @users.website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, external, link-to

I'm working on a website that allows users to create an account. One of the attributes when creating a user is a users personal website. When I try to use the users website like this:

```
<%= link_to @user.site, @user.url %>
```

The url that gets generated is: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/www.userswebsite.com`

I think this is because of the @user part of the link_to... but how can I get this to link to www.userwebsite.com ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like you need to stick the protocol on your link.  E.g. you have www.userswebsite.com in your database, it should be http://www.userswebsite.com

Comment: this works but relies on being able to always keep a sanitized url in the database, which may not always be possible...see the Voldy answer for one that sanitizes on its way out

Answer (score 97):

You can prepend url with protocol if it's absent:

```
module UrlHelper
  def url_with_protocol(url)
    /^http/i.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}"
  end
end
```

And then:

```
link_to @user.site, url_with_protocol(@user.url), :target => '_blank'
```

Comment: Use :target => '_blank' instead of :target => :blank. It doesn't work as expected, you can try it by opening the same link from the newly created window.

Comment: If my URL doesn't include `www.` then my app considers it an internal link. E.g. `http://example.com` links to the current page.

Answer (score 3):

You are storing URLs without the http:// so they are being interpreted as relative URLs.
Try this:
link_to @user.site, "http://#{@user.url}"

Answer (score 1):

Try out the awesome gem [Domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix):

Then you can simply parse the URL on the fly with:

```
<%= Domainatrix.parse(@user.url).url %>
```

Better yet, create a `before_save` action in your user model that parses the url before saving it.

```
before_save :parse_url

def parse_url
  if self.url
    self.url = Domainatrix.parse(self.url).url
  end
end
```

Here are some samples of what you can do with Domainatrix:

```
url = Domainatrix.parse("http://www.pauldix.net")
url.url       # => "http://www.pauldix.net" (the original url)
url.public_suffix       # => "net"
url.domain    # => "pauldix"
url.canonical # => "net.pauldix"

url = Domainatrix.parse("http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk/asdf.html?q=arg")
url.public_suffix       # => "co.uk"
url.domain    # => "pauldix"
url.subdomain # => "foo.bar"
url.path      # => "/asdf.html?q=arg"
url.canonical # => "uk.co.pauldix.bar.foo/asdf.html?q=arg"
```