# How do I defined a variable link_to to an external URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

On my site a user has a personal profile with a link to his personal external website. The url of the sites I store in a postgresql database under the name **website**. When I test the result, I always get a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/www.example.com
```

instead of `http://www.example.com`

My view **index.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All projects') %>
<h1>All projects</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="microposts">
    <%= render @microposts %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

and my **_micropost.html.erb** like this:

```
<li>
    <span class="title"><%= micropost.title %></span>
    <span class="website"><%= link_to micropost.website, micropost.website %></span>
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
</li>
```

I don't know what's the problem in this case. If I set a @ before **micropost.website** it gives me an error **undefined method `website' for nil:NilClass**

Does anyone can help me (I'm a RoR beginner)?

KR, Fabian

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012188/rails-link-to-external-site-url-is-attribute-of-user-table-like-users-websit

Comment: not really. If I write `<span class="website"><%= link_to micropost.website, micropost.website %></span>` in my **_micropost.html.erb**, I get also an **undefined method `website' for nil:NilClass** error

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't you first get `undefined method title for nil:NilClass` in the line above it? `<span class="title"><%= micropost.title %></span>`

Comment: @JoeFrambach no, `<%= micropost.title %>` works fine, but if I would change this to `<%= @micropost.title %>` instead, I get also the same error (but this time for the title)

Comment: So how is this not a duplicate

Comment: @JoeFrambach sorry, this is some kind of a duplicated question, but for a beginner much more usefull than the other questions. Hope it could left as a hint for newbies.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It sounds like you are storing URLs without the `http://` so they are being interpreted as relative URLs. You just need to do something like this:

```
link_to micropost.website, "http://#{micropost.website}"
```

or maybe add a `full_url` method to that model that adds it if it's missing.

By the way, you can't use `@micropost` in that partial because it doesn't exist (you only have `@microposts` or `micropost`).

Comment: thanks, have tried this and it works well. Sorry but for me as a beginner the above answers were not clear enough to see the similarity between my problem and the problem in the mentioned other stack overflow-question. Sorry for this newbie dumb brain ;-)

Answer (score 24):

You can try with this below code:

`<%= link_to "your label", "your link with http", :target => "_blank" %>`

This will create a link that opens in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like that:

```
link_to micropost.website, url_for(micropost.website)
```

See [Rails Api: url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for)

You can experiment in rails console.
Just type in console:

```
micropost = Micropost.first
helper.link_to micropost.website, url_for(micropost.website)
```

And you see a result string.

Also you need to learn the difference between path and url helpers.
See [ruby on rails guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

Goro rights. You need to add "http://" to your website attribute.
After validating and before save Model instance to database you need to add this prefix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ruby [URI class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html#method-c-build)

```
= link_to micropost.website, URI::HTTP.build({:host => micropost.website}).to_s, target: "_blank"

# <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
```

Comment: Note that if ‘website´ contains a protocol like 'https', 'http' or even 'ftp', an error will be raised

Answer (score 0):

I use the [postrank-uri](https://github.com/postrank-labs/postrank-uri) gem to normalize the url before passing it to `link_to`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def normalized_webpage
    webpage && PostRank::URI.normalize(webpage).to_s
  end
end
```

Then you can use `link_to "website", user.normalized_webpage, target: "_blank"` in your view. This will for example add the `http://` to the url, if it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Rails 5 and I had the same problem. All I need to do to fix it, was to include the protocol on my `link_to` tag. E.g. I had ***`www.google.com.mx`***, then, it should be ***`http://www.google.com.mx`***. And that's it it works just fine like in the [official doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is mentioned.

So, finally I just have something like this in my view:

```
<%= link_to (content_tag(:i, "help", class: 'material-icons tiny')), " http://www.google.com.mx", target: "_blank", rel: "alternate" %>
```

Which is the same as:

```
<%= link_to "help", "http://www.google.com.mx", target: "_blank", rel: "alternate" %>
```

I hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what i did.

Let's say we have @person and he has a link (@person.link) # => www.google.com

in your helpers create something like this

```
def extlink(link)

 if link.include?("http://")
  puts link
 else
  link.insert(0, "http://")
  link
 end
```

end

And in your file you can do

```
<% @person.each do |p| %>

<%= link_to 'External', extlink(p.link) %>

<% end %>
```

Works for me

Comment: This won't work for links to other protocols, such as `https://`, `ftp://`, or the wide range of application protocols like `spotify://` - perhaps just match `://` if you want to use this method. Having said all that though, it would be better to validate the URL on input

Comment: Maybe not perfect, but got me the idea. Thanks!