# How to add link field in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I am trying to add a link field to a form. The link should be clickable when displayed. When I run

```
rails generate migration AddLinkToThings link:xxxx
```

What should xxx be? I've tried `link:string`, but that just puts out a string, of course.

Here is how I am making the title of a Thing link to where the user specifies:

```
<strong><%= link_to @thing.title, @thing.link %></strong>
```

The problem is that @thing.link is linking to the show page for the Thing, and **not** the link that the user typed in. It's ultra confusing to explain.

For example, when I created this Thing, I linked it to google.com, but instead, it's linking  to mywebsite.com/things/7. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Create a view which renders the link with `link_to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a string, but then you'd just use it inside of a `link_to` helper in your view.

Depending on the contents of the string, you may need to append `.html_safe` to the string inside the `link_to` tag.

**Update**

Based on your edit, I think you'll want to interpolate `@thing.link` inside a string.

Example:

```
<strong><%= link_to @thing.title, "#{@thing.link.try(:html_safe_}" %></strong>
```

If `link` will *never* be nil, you don't need the `try`.

Comment: Okay. That's worked. I'll update the question with a little problem that's occurring, though.

Comment: Awesome, but I'm getting "undefined method html_safe for nil:NilClass" Lol

@CDub

Comment: `link` on `@thing` in that case is nil

Comment: @DylanRichards does `@thing.link` have a value? you should check for a value in your code or add a default value.

Comment: I'll check for a value. Give me a second

Comment: Ah. Link does appear to be `nil` from the console. I think I have an old tutorial that will help me actually save the link when the Thing is created. I'll get back to you all if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Okay. I got the link to save on the creation of the Thing. But now when I click the link, it routes to www.mysite.com/things/www.google.com. What's this about?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721816/how-do-i-defined-a-variable-link-to-to-an-external-url - if you're storing the URL without `http`, you need to prepend it to the string in the `link_to`, otherwise it treats it as a relative URL.