# Rails: Having a small issue with link_to and external URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty new to rails. I'm doing a project where a user submits a url and a title. The *title* is supposed to link to the *url* provided by the user. The url is stored as a param for `link`.

Here's the code from the index view:

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <%= link_to link.title, link.url %>
  <%= link_to "comments", link %>
<% end %>
```

This works, for the most part.

The problem occurs if the submitted url doesn't begin with `http://`. As it is, it's pointing to `http://localhost:3000/google.com` and I get an error `No route matches [GET] "/google.com"`

How could I get around this? I tried changing it to:

```
<%= link_to link.title, "http://#{link.url}" %>
```

Which makes `google.com` work, but then `http://google.com` turns into `http://http//google.com` somehow.

I'm sure the fix will be a face palm moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend url with protocol if it's absent:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def url_with_protocol(url)
    /^http/i.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}"
  end
end

<%= link_to link.title, url_with_protocol(link.url) %>
```

answer derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012188/rails-link-to-external-site-url-is-attribute-of-user-table-like-users-websit#answer-5021931) SO question/answer

Comment: Thanks Miles. Where would I put that module?

Comment: Derp! Thanks a lot Miles! This plus a variation of the answer from @jeffersonchoi solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your input field, you can do something like `<input type="text" name="url" value="http://">` so that your url will always started with http://. User can also manually changed it to https if needed.

Also I may add a `full_url` method to the model that adds it if it's missing.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but what if the user is annoying and deletes the `http://` from the field before submitting, then get that error?

Comment: @tdog Then I would do the same thing as the answer below showed. To prepend the url if it's absent. I would say it's better to have `http://` included in frontend, and backend to be a safe check to see if i need to prepend the url or not.

Comment: Thanks, got it working smoothly now :) Learning something every day!